# Prove or disprove the given inequality involving partial sums of exponential series

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, inequality

Let $a>0$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. If $a>n,\,$ then, is it possible to have $$\dfrac{\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor a/2 \rfloor} \frac{a^i}{i!}}{\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{a^i}{i!}}> 1/2$$

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: No. For example: choose $n=1$ and $a=\frac 32$.

Comment: Isn't the LHS is 1 in this case so 1> 1/2 ?

Comment: For n=1, a=3/2, $\lfloor a/2\rfloor=0$ so numerator is 1 but denominator is $1+3/2=5/2$ so LHS=$2/5=0.4\lt 1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very sure about what do you mean by the inequality being "possible" here.

If you are looking for a solution of a, to a given n, such that the above inequality is true, you can choose any $a \geq 2n$, and you can see that the numerator is greater than the denominator and hence the expression is greater than 1.

Comment: I believe this inequality must be true for all $a>n$, though I'm not sure how to prove it. The case $a>2n$ is trivial.

Comment: Exactly. So, were you asking for proof of this inequality, because then your questions was a little ill-framed?

Comment: yes, or a counter-example

Comment: The counter-example of $a = 1.5$ and $n=1$ is right. The LHS evaluates to $1/2.5$ which is less than 0.5